# I am getting an Error because I have to use an array, to render a collection of child, although I using an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-props

In my main Home.js Component, I am getting my (scream) Data from my Database.
(I am getting that successfully)
I am rendering that Data in another Component(Scream.js). I am passing that Data to Home by using props
But I am getting that error.

Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {_seconds, _nanoseconds}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

I really do not get it !!

Home

```
   import { Grid } from '@material-ui/core'
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
import Scream from '../components/Scream'

    export class home extends Component {
        state = {
        screams: null
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get('/screams')
            .then(res => {
                console.log(res.data)
                this.setState({
                    screams: res.data // Thats where the error is Comming // //But thats already an array
                })
            })
            .catch(err => console.log(err))
    }


    render() {
        let recentScreamsMarkup = this.state.screams ? (
            this.state.screams.map((scream) => <Scream scream={scream} />)
        ) : (
                <p> loading ....</p>
            );
 

     return (
            <Grid container spacing={16}>
                <Grid item sm={8} xs={12}>
                    {recentScreamsMarkup}
                </Grid>
                <Grid item sm={4} xs={12}>
                    <p>Profile........</p>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        )
    }
}

export default home
```

Scream Component

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react'

import withStyles from '@material-ui/core/styles/withStyles';
import Card from '@material-ui/core/Card';
import CardContent from '@material-ui/core/CardContent';
import CardMedia from '@material-ui/core/CardMedia';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';

    const styles = {
        card: {
            display: 'flex'
        }
    }
    
    
    class Scream extends Component {
        render() {
            const { classes, scream: { body, createdAt, userImage, userHandle, screamId, likeCount, commentCount } } = this.props
    
            return (
            <Card>
                <CardMedia
                    image={userImage}
                    title="Profile image" />
                <CardContent>
                    <Typography variant="h5">{userHandle}</Typography>
                    <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary">{createdAt}</Typography>
                    <Typography variant="body1">{body}</Typography>
                </CardContent>
            </Card>
        )
    }
}

export default withStyles(styles)(Scream);
```

Comment: Could you also add `render` function's body? The reason why React is printing such error is probably right inside of it.

Comment: Could you explaine what you mean :)

Comment: `return` statement is missing - I can only see the word, but nothing besides.

Comment: oh sure one minute please

Comment: You can see the return Statement

Comment: Better but not enough - Home's return is still missing :)

Comment: ohh sry 1 minute again

Comment: Now it is complete

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228492/discussion-between-aitwar-and-daniel-ragimov).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Issue was resolved in the chat. Following post is a summary of findings and solutions.*

`console.log(res.data)` produced following result:

```
(12) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}] 
0: {screamId: "sOO4pudfYNpokUg3JW9x", body: "ich will schlafen amkkkkkgtrtrgtrgrtgtrk", userHandle: "userfinal", createdAt: "2021-02-05T00:51:04.998Z"} 
1: {screamId: "cWGTIceqH71nDIl2EMdN", body: "ich will schlafen amkkkkkk", userHandle: "userfinal", createdAt: "2021-02-05T00:49:57.555Z"} 
2: {screamId: "tqeMfYmtdw220uadZT7R", body: "ich will schlafen amk", userHandle: "test", createdAt: "2021-02-05T00:47:20.842Z"} 
3: {screamId: "m1BZnHSYj2ks94ZJBC4t", body: "ich will schlafen amk", userHandle: "test", createdAt: "2021-02-05T00:44:16.987Z"} 
4: {screamId: "csHMdyb1OaoIvZCx7gr1", body: "vsvsddsv", userHandle: "test", createdAt: "2021-02-04T23:27:47.885Z"} 
5: {screamId: "0UnVjTD67ByBnqF8Lyer", body: "Neeeewscream6", userHandle: "newdaniel5", createdAt: "2021-02-03T23:17:07.542Z"} 
6: {screamId: "AlGUIph01Hwaoy3axOzN", body: "Neeeewscream5", userHandle: "newdaniel5", createdAt: "2021-01-31T23:52:25.701Z"} 
7: {screamId: "07AKWthRJB1DzmiUxmbD", body: "Neeeewscream", userHandle: "newdaniel", createdAt: {…}} 
8: {screamId: "trnxtkiI7HWR9NTUmecr", body: "New screamzwei", userHandle: "new", createdAt: {…}} 
9: {screamId: "MobOBBFiHN3raEPEeW2i", body: "New scream", userHandle: "new", createdAt: {…}} 
10: {screamId: "dbLSJURg6n0uwIsSMr4I", body: "Second Scream", userHandle: "user", createdAt: {…}} 
11: {screamId: "Nz22dq42tjq5m1jBTTfy", body: "First scream , ahhhhhhh", userHandle: "user", createdAt: {…}} 
length: 12 
__proto__: Array(0)
```

As you can see, `createdAt` is an object starting from index `7`. That's why React is complaining - it cannot render objects. Handle it properly by detecting if `createdAt` is an object or take a look at your backend code and make sure it's always a string.